# Class not found after composer require

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm learning php and composer following the [article](https://www.frobiovox.com/posts/2016/08/16/basic-hello-world-with-composer-and-php.html)

I try to use external dependancy `composer require phpunit/php-timer`.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "ypapax/composer_php_hello_world_log4php",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": ">= 7.2",
    "phpunit/php-timer": "^2.1@dev"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "HelloWorld": "src/"
    },
    "classname": {
      "PHP_Timer": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

and my `test.php`:

```
<?php

// Autoload files using Composer autoloader.
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use HelloWorld\Greetings;

echo Greetings::sayHelloWorld();
```

Where greetings.php is

```
<?php

namespace HelloWorld;

use PHP_Timer;

class Greetings
{
    public static function sayHelloWorld()
    {
        $timer = new PHP_Timer();
        $timer . start();
        return 'Hello World\n' . $timer->resourceUsage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run the test `php tests/test.php`
it gives me an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_Timer' not found in composer_php_hello_world_log4php/src/HelloWorld/Greetings.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 composer_php_hello_world_log4php/tests/test.php(8): HelloWorld\Greetings::sayHelloWorld()
#1 {main}
  thrown in composer_php_hello_world_log4php/src/HelloWorld/Greetings.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_Timer' not found in composer_php_hello_world_log4php/src/HelloWorld/Greetings.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 composer_php_hello_world_log4php/tests/test.php(8): HelloWorld\Greetings::sayHelloWorld()
#1 {main}
  thrown in composer_php_hello_world_log4php/src/HelloWorld/Greetings.php on line 11
```

I guess something wrong is in composer.json:

```
"classname": {
      "PHP_Timer": "src/"
    }
```

PHP version:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2019 18:07:55) ( NTS )
```

Link to my [test repo](https://github.com/ypapax/composer_php_hello_world_log4php)

## Update

Here is my file `autoload_namespaces.php`:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'HelloWorld' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

And autoload_classmap.php:

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'SebastianBergmann\\Timer\\Exception' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-timer/src/Exception.php',
    'SebastianBergmann\\Timer\\RuntimeException' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-timer/src/RuntimeException.php',
    'SebastianBergmann\\Timer\\Timer' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-timer/src/Timer.php',
);
```

Comment: he PSR-0 references are all combined, during install/update, into a single `key => value` array. Have you checked the generated file `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php.`

Comment: @lovelace I added file `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` content above

Comment: `classname` [is not a valid composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) key. Maybe you meant `classmap`?

Comment: You forgot the `use` statement. It happens, no biggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` statement was missing from the `Greetings` class:

```
<?php

namespace HelloWorld;

use SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer;

class Greetings
{
    public static function sayHelloWorld()
    {
        $timer = new Timer();
        $timer::start();
        return 'Hello World\n' . $timer->resourceUsage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

and this can be removed from `composer.json`:

```
    "classname": {
      "PHP_Timer": "src/"
     }
```

Comment: Also take a look at [the manual about Using namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading the right `namespace`. I suggest you to checkout the [examples](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/php-timer) on the package page

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need this in your `composer.json`:

```
"classname": {
  "PHP_Timer": "src/"
}
```

According to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer/blob/master/src/Timer.php you need

```
use SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer as PHP_Timer;
```

in your `greetings.php` file.